# items hidden by filters - error console

Tags: node.js, angular, console, electron, chromium

Estou criando uma aplicação em electron com angular2, onde faço solicitações à uma api. Ao desconectar a maquina da internet, (pois desejo que a aplicação funcione de maneira diferente sem internet) no console se inicia vários erros com o titulo  "items hidden by filters", como mostrado na imagem.

Essa contagem aumenta muito rápido, apenas enquanto o computador está sem conexão à internet, ao reconectar o contador fica pausado.

Gostaria de saber se isto é comum em aplicações deste tipo, que utilizam Chromium e o Node.js. Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: items hiddem by filters console chromium]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta apertar com o botao direito no console >filter >unhide all

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTJRe.png[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta opção fica bloqueada no meu console da aplicação do electron por alguma razão. Em pesquisas, me recomendaram alterar o filtro para "verbose", porém não obtive nenhuma informação nova no console